# Is $\mathcal L_1 \cup \mathcal L_2$ a DCFL, if and only if $\mathcal L_1 \cap \mathcal L_2$ is a DCFL?

Tags: formal-languages, automata, context-free-grammar

Let $\newcommand{\lang}{\mathcal L}\lang_1$ and $\lang_2$ be deterministic context free languages, the set of which is denoted by $D$. Is $\lang_1 \cup \lang_2 \in D$, if and only if $\lang_1 \cap\lang_2 \in D$?

#### Some thoughts

I don't think this is true. Assuming $\lang_1$ and $\lang_2$ are DCFLs, there are corresponding deterministic pushdown automata $A_1$ and $A_2$ that recognize them. Let's assume the acceptance happens via accepting states.

As per usual, if we look at the union language, we could construct a product automaton $A_1 \times A_2$ and choose its accepting states, so that in the case of the union $\lang_1\cup\lang_2$ it accepts the language if either or both of the automata are in their accepting states. With the intersection automaton, we choose the accepting states so that both $A_1$ and $A_2$ have to be in their accepting states.

By this logic, assuming that $\lang_1 \cup \lang_2 \in D$ is not a strong enough condition to conclude that $\lang_1\cap\lang_2 \in D$. This is because the automaton that recognizes a union might also recognize a language that is not in the intersection language. Therefore the claim is false.

#### The actual questions

Is the above logic even starting to point in the right direction? If this is the case, I would of course have to come up with good counterexamples. One of these might be something like the pair
$\lang_1 = \newcommand{\set}[1]{\left\{#1\right\}}\set{a b^n c^n \mid n \in \mathbb N_0}$, $\lang_2 = \set{b^m c^{2m} \mid m \in \mathbb N_0}$. The union of these is in $D$, but so is their intersection, the empty set $\emptyset$. Maybe by modifying these just a little bit I might arrive at a solution?

Also, is there a better way of looking at this, maybe via grammar productions, even if my idea was good enough? The grammar productions that result in the languages $\lang_1$ and $\lang_2$ are
$$\newcommand{\rewrite}{\longrightarrow}
S_1 \rewrite c \qquad V_1 \rewrite ab \qquad W_1 \rewrite SA \mid S aAb
$$
and 
$$
S_2 \rewrite \epsilon \mid abb \mid aSbb \,.
$$
But how might I use these (or the modified versions of them) to show the wanted result?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $L_1 = \{a^nb^n \mid n > 0 \}$ and $L_2 = \{a^nb^{2n} \mid n > 0 \}$. Then $L_1 \cap L_2$ is empty, and hence deterministic. However, $L_1 \cup L_2$ is not deterministic. Furthermore $L_1^c \cup L_2^c = (L_1 \cap L_2)^c$ is deterministic, but $L_1^c \cap L_2^c = (L_1 \cup L_2)^c$ is not deterministic, otherwise its complement $L_1 \cup L_2$ would be deterministic. This gives a counterexample for the two directions of your question.